# Survival time tie-handling using aareg in R's survival package

Tags: r, regression, survival, data-mining

I have noticed in the CRAN documentation for the `survival` package that survival time tie-handling is discussed extensively for Cox-PH regression (allowing for Efron, Breslow, or Exact methods), but not for Aalen's Additive Model.  How would the below function call handle a tie in `DURATION`?

`aareg(formula = Surv(DURATION, OBSERVED) ~ regressor1 + regressor2 -1, data=df, nmin = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/timereg/html/aalen.html:

"The program assumes that there are no ties, and if such are present random noise is added to break the ties."

Also note the same assumption in one of R's time-varying Cox model's, timecox. See for example,
ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/timereg/timereg.pdf

If you dig into the code, you could tinker with different tie-breaking schemes. I also recommend the python package Lifelines (AalenAdditiveFitter); I found the code easier to follow (by a mile).